# Thanking for scheduling meeting

Tags: word-choice, email

I am going to send a email to a secretary of a CEO thanking her for scheduling a meeting.

What would be a good phrase for the opening of email? Should I write:

> Thank you for scheduling the meeting

or would it be more appropriate to write:

> Thank you for accommodating our request

Comment: Are you concerned that one or the other is grammatically incorrect? Otherwise this is about etiquette, not language.

Comment: I've flagged this for closure as off-topic (proofreading), since no specific issue other than "which would be a good phrase" has been identified.

Answer (score 1):

Either answer is fine, but

> Thank you for accommodating our request

is much more friendly than the first one, which is formal. It depends what approach or how familiar you are with the CEO/their secretary.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon what you actually wish to thank her for. They're not the same thing.

*Thanking her for scheduling the meeting* is just that. Performing a task that is part of her daily routine.  It sounds like perfunctory or reflexive politeness, not recognizing any particular effort on her part.

*Thank you for accommodating our request* sounds like she made an effort to assist you. That you had some scheduling requirements that made if necessary to shift some items on her boss's schedule.   For many CEOs, changing their schedule is a Herculean task.   So, to thank her for this sounds more genuine and less perfunctory.